# html php 3 submit button to pass values to 3 different pages

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a page that contains a List box containing a list of categories taken from a mysql database, 4 iframe elements and 4 submit button (code to follow)

When an item is selected from the List box the onchange event submits the page to jobs.php and loads it into the joblist iframe. Once the iframe is loaded and visible it makes the "Add Job To Category" submit button visible. This all works great

When I click the "Add Job To Category" Submit button it loads Jobnew.php into the jobed iframe this is working but I can not seem to figure out how to pass the selected item from the List box using this submit button

I hope I am clear in my question if not please advise
any help is very much appreciated....

Jobtask.php

```php
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Job Configuration</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute;left:5px;top:0px;width:1345px;height:50px;z-index:0;">
<img src="images/img0001.png" id="Shape1" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:1345px;height:50px;"></div>
<span style='position:fixed;left:525px;top:8px;font-family:Arial;font-size:32px;width:275px;'>Job Configuration</span>
<form action='index.html' target='' method='post'>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:205px;top:55px;width:1345px;height:50px;z-index:0;">
  <Input type="submit" action="index.html" Target="_top" method='post'Value="Main Menu">
 </div>
</form>
<form style=position:fixed;left:200px;top:82px;>    
 <iframe name='joblist' id='joblist' style=position:fixed;left:200px;top:px;visibility:hidden;z-index:10 src='' height="475" width="1150" scrolling='yes' frameBorder='0' ></iframe>    
 <iframe name='job' id='job' style=absolute:fixed;left:200px;top:0px;visibility:hidden;z-index:0 src='' height="475" width="1150" scrolling='yes' frameBorder='0' ></iframe>    
 <iframe name='jobed' id='jobed' style=position:fixed;left:460px;top:150px;visibility:hidden;z-index:10 src='' height="217" width="350" scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' ></iframe>   
 <iframe name='newcat' id='newcat' style=position:fixed;left:460px;top:150px;visibility:hidden;z-index:10 src='' height="125" width="350" scrolling='no' frameBorder='0' ></iframe> 
</form>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('dbcon/dbconnect.php');
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $insql= "INSERT INTO catagory (Catagory) VALUES ('$_REQUEST[newcat]')";
  $con->query($insql);
  }
$Catresult = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT CatID, Catagory FROM catagory");

echo "<div id='wb_CatSel' style='position:absolute;z-index:0;text-align:center;'bgcolor='#00b0e6';>";
echo "<span style='position:fixed;left:10px;top:82px;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;background-color:#00b0e6;width:175px;'>Select Category</span></div>";
echo "<form action='jobs.php' target='joblist' style='position:fixed;left:10px;top:101px;'></td>";

echo "<select name='cat' size='11' style='width: 175px;' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Catresult))
{ 
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['CatID']."\">".$row['Catagory']."</option>\n  ";
}

echo "</select>";

echo "</form>";

echo "<form action='Jobnew.php' target='jobed' method='post'>";
echo "<div style='position:absolute;left:10px;top:285px;width:1345px;height:50px;z-index:0;'>";
echo "<Input type='hidden' id='id1'><Input type='submit' id='sbtn' style='width:175px;visibility:hidden;'   Value='Add Job To Category'></div></form>";

echo "<form action='Jobtask.php' target='' method='post'>";
echo "<div style='position:absolute;left:10px;top:310px;width:1345px;height:50px;z-index:0;'>";
echo "<Input type='submit' style='width:175px;' action='Jobtask.php' Target='_top' method='post'  Value='Reset Form'></div></form>";

echo "<form action='newcat.php' target='newcat' method='post'>";
echo "<div style='position:absolute;left:10px;top:335px;width:1345px;height:50px;z-index:0;''>";
echo "<Input type='submit' style='width:175px;'' action='newcat.php' Target='newcat' method='post'  Value='Add New Category'></div></form>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't use iframes. use divs and and ajax requests instead

Comment: are you saying that i can not accomplish this using iframes?  When I click on the listbox it submits with the value why can that value be passed with the submit button?  I am so confused????

Comment: you can, but it'd be a lot easier without using frames

Comment: perhaps easier if i knew and understood ajax but being as I don't can anyone help me accomplish this using iframes?  PLEASE

Comment: Not trying to seem like a butt hole here but you mean someone has the time to edit my post, correct spelling and such but no one can offer anything other than use ajax????  This don't seem very helpful to me.